# IIS Does Not Process Request Right Away

Tags: c#, performance, web-services, wcf, iis

I have a Windows Service installed on 8 servers that makes a call into our app tier (made up of 15 servers). All of these servers are on the same internal network, so they don't need to cross "the internet". For some reason, every now and then we will see the request into the app tier takes several minutes to complete, when it usually only takes 1 or 2 seconds. When this happens, it will often happen with several of the instances on different servers. By running Fiddler on the Windows Service server, I can see that the entire time is spent waiting for the request to get a response back (not in the Windows Service process itself trying to spin up threads or get other resources or anything).

I've added logging to right before and after the call is made from the Windows Service code, as well as at the very start and end of the function being called in the IIS Service. When the problem happens, I can see that the IIS Service function still completes within a second or two, but that there is a few minute delay between when the request is made from the Windows Service to when the IIS Service function actually starts running.

I have also been able to reproduce this issue when modifying the Windows Service server's `hosts` file to point it directly to an individual app server, bypassing the firewall and load balancer, so it seems to be a problem with IIS on the app server itself.

Here is how my WCF Service bindings are configured on the app servers:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824">
                <security mode="Transport"></security>
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="DefaultBindingConfiguration"
                transactionFlow="true"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                messageEncoding="Mtom"
                maxBufferPoolSize="1073741824"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824"
                sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                openTimeout="00:10:00"
                closeTimeout="00:10:00">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="1073741824"
                    maxStringContentLength="1073741824"
                    maxArrayLength="1073741824"
                    maxBytesPerRead="1073741824"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="1073741824"/>
                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="DefaultBindingConfigurationNoMessageCredential"
                transactionFlow="true"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                messageEncoding="Mtom"
                maxBufferPoolSize="1073741824"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824"
                sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                openTimeout="00:10:00"
                closeTimeout="00:10:00">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="1073741824"
                    maxStringContentLength="1073741824"
                    maxArrayLength="1073741824"
                    maxBytesPerRead="1073741824"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="1073741824"/>
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="DefaultServiceBehavior">
                <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="160" maxConcurrentSessions="100" maxConcurrentInstances="100" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
            </behavior>
            <behavior name="DefaultServiceBehaviorNoMessageCredential">
                <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="160" maxConcurrentSessions="100" maxConcurrentInstances="100"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <diagnostics performanceCounters="All" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

I'm looking for any ideas why there is this delay between when the request is made and when the IIS Service function actually receives the request, or additional things I can do to troubleshoot the issue to get more information. Any thoughts or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

## Update

This problem does not seem to be caused by the application pool on the app server restarting; there is no logs of an app pool crash or restart in the event viewer logs.

Comment: You should open a support case with Microsoft if you are not familiar with IIS. To me it seems to be related to exhausted thread pool in the worker process, but more information like performance counters and hang dumps should be collected and analyzed.

Comment: Check from the IIS side to make sure the app pools aren't restarting for some reason (either scheduled or some other trigger)

Comment: @Peter4499 We do schedule the app pool to restart nightly, but we see this problem intermittently a few times a day. Also, I checked the event logs and there are no reports of unexpected restarts.